# How to obtain exact results with CGAL Filtered Predicate

Tags: predicate, cgal, robustness

I've implemented some code that uses filtered predicate of cgal. I am defining my own filtered predicate to use Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel at first and then Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel at second if the first call fails. I thougt that if there occurs some ambiguity with the computations inside filtered predicate, then it understands and turns to use exact constructions and reaches the exact results in the end. However, I saw this is not the case. Inside my filtered predicate, I am computing a point on a plane and checking the orientation of this point with respect to this plane. My expectation was that it would return CGAL::COPLANAR. However, it returns CGAL::NEGATIVE. If there occurred some ambiguity with inexact constructions, then does not filtered kernel understand it? How does filtered kernel work? Does not it throw an exception and repeat the operations with the second template argument? Or are the data types that I use a wrong choice?

Edit: By the way, when I put the point into the plane equation it prints -1.05501e-10. Should I change EPSILON value used by CGAL. If yes, how should I do it?

You can find my code below:

```
template <typename K>
struct ClosestPlaneToPoint_1D {

typedef typename K::RT                      RT;
typedef typename K::Point_3                 Point_3;
typedef typename K::Plane_3                 Plane_3;
typedef typename K::Line_3                  Line_3;
typedef typename CGAL::Comparison_result    result_type;

result_type operator()( Point_3 plane1_p1, Point_3 plane1_p2, Point_3 plane1_p3,
                        Point_3 plane2_p1, Point_3 plane2_p2, Point_3 plane2_p3, 
                        Point_3 candidate_plane_p1, Point_3 candidate_plane_p2, Point_3 candidate_plane_p3,
                        Point_3 front_plane_p1, Point_3 front_plane_p2, Point_3 front_plane_p3,
                        Point_3 back_plane_p1, Point_3 back_plane_p2, Point_3 back_plane_p3) const
{
    Plane_3 plane1(plane1_p1, plane1_p2, plane1_p3);
    Plane_3 plane2(plane2_p1, plane2_p2, plane2_p3);

    Plane_3 candidate_plane(candidate_plane_p1, candidate_plane_p2, candidate_plane_p3);
    if (CGAL::parallel(candidate_plane, plane1) || CGAL::parallel(candidate_plane, plane2))
        return CGAL::SMALLER;   // not valid

    auto auto_line = CGAL::intersection(plane1, plane2);
    Line_3* line = boost::get<Line_3>(&*auto_line);

    auto auto_candidate_point = CGAL::intersection(candidate_plane, *line);
    Point_3* candidate_point = boost::get<Point_3>(&*auto_candidate_point);

    if (candidate_point == NULL)
        return CGAL::SMALLER;

    CGAL::Sign sign = CGAL::orientation(back_plane_p1, back_plane_p2, back_plane_p3, *candidate_point);
    cout << "SIGN: " << sign << endl;
    Plane_3 back_plane2(back_plane_p1, back_plane_p2, back_plane_p3);
    cout << "PLACEMENT: " << back_plane2.a() * candidate_point->x() + back_plane2.b() * candidate_point->y() + back_plane2.c() * candidate_point->z() + back_plane2.d() << endl;
    if (sign == CGAL::POSITIVE)
        return CGAL::SMALLER;
    if (sign == CGAL::COPLANAR) {
        Plane_3 back_plane(back_plane_p1, back_plane_p2, back_plane_p3);
        if (CGAL::parallel(back_plane, candidate_plane) &&
            CGAL::scalar_product(back_plane.orthogonal_vector(), candidate_plane.orthogonal_vector()) > 0)
            return CGAL::SMALLER;
    }

    Plane_3 front_plane(front_plane_p1, front_plane_p2, front_plane_p3);
    auto auto_front_point = CGAL::intersection(front_plane, *line);
    Point_3* front_point = boost::get<Point_3>(&*auto_front_point);

    Plane_3 back_plane(back_plane_p1, back_plane_p2, back_plane_p3);
    auto auto_back_point = CGAL::intersection(back_plane, *line);
    Point_3* back_point = boost::get<Point_3>(&*auto_back_point);
    
    RT distance1 = CGAL::squared_distance(*back_point, *front_point);
    RT distance2 = CGAL::squared_distance(*back_point, *candidate_point);
    return CGAL::compare(distance1, distance2);
}

};

typedef CGAL::Filtered_predicate<ClosestPlaneToPoint_1D<ExK>, 
ClosestPlaneToPoint_1D<InK>, C2ExK, C2InK>  CP_1D;
```

The above code computes the intersection point of plane1, plane2 and candidate_plane whose points are given in the arguments. Next the point is checked whether it is in front of the back_plane or not. The input that I give produces an intersection point locating on back_plane. But when it checks the point position with respect to back_plane, it says that it is on the positive side of the back_plane.

Comment: I think you should post the code of your predicate, and describe the expected behavior. `EPIC_kernel` use double as number type so any construction is inexact. A point constructed will never (in general) belong to a non-axis aligned plane. The free function `CGAL::exact(o)` called on any primitive of `EPEC_kernel` will return the exact version of the object without filters.

Comment: The code is a bit complex, yet I add it into the question.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should be working:

```
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>

template <typename K>
struct ClosestPlaneToPoint_1D_imp {

typedef typename K::RT                      RT;
typedef typename K::Point_3                 Point_3;
typedef typename K::Plane_3                 Plane_3;
typedef typename K::Line_3                  Line_3;
typedef typename CGAL::Comparison_result    result_type;

result_type operator()( Point_3 plane1_p1, Point_3 plane1_p2, Point_3 plane1_p3,
                        Point_3 plane2_p1, Point_3 plane2_p2, Point_3 plane2_p3,
                        Point_3 candidate_plane_p1, Point_3 candidate_plane_p2, Point_3 candidate_plane_p3,
                        Point_3 front_plane_p1, Point_3 front_plane_p2, Point_3 front_plane_p3,
                        Point_3 back_plane_p1, Point_3 back_plane_p2, Point_3 back_plane_p3) const
{
    Plane_3 plane1(plane1_p1, plane1_p2, plane1_p3);
    Plane_3 plane2(plane2_p1, plane2_p2, plane2_p3);

    Plane_3 candidate_plane(candidate_plane_p1, candidate_plane_p2, candidate_plane_p3);
    if (CGAL::parallel(candidate_plane, plane1) || CGAL::parallel(candidate_plane, plane2))
        return CGAL::SMALLER;   // not valid

    auto auto_line = CGAL::intersection(plane1, plane2);
    Line_3* line = boost::get<Line_3>(&*auto_line);

    auto auto_candidate_point = CGAL::intersection(candidate_plane, *line);
    Point_3* candidate_point = boost::get<Point_3>(&*auto_candidate_point);

    if (candidate_point == NULL)
        return CGAL::SMALLER;

    CGAL::Sign sign = CGAL::orientation(back_plane_p1, back_plane_p2, back_plane_p3, *candidate_point);
    Plane_3 back_plane2(back_plane_p1, back_plane_p2, back_plane_p3);
    if (sign == CGAL::POSITIVE)
        return CGAL::SMALLER;
    if (sign == CGAL::COPLANAR) {
        Plane_3 back_plane(back_plane_p1, back_plane_p2, back_plane_p3);
        if (CGAL::parallel(back_plane, candidate_plane) &&
            CGAL::scalar_product(back_plane.orthogonal_vector(), candidate_plane.orthogonal_vector()) > 0)
            return CGAL::SMALLER;
    }

    Plane_3 front_plane(front_plane_p1, front_plane_p2, front_plane_p3);
    auto auto_front_point = CGAL::intersection(front_plane, *line);
    Point_3* front_point = boost::get<Point_3>(&*auto_front_point);

    Plane_3 back_plane(back_plane_p1, back_plane_p2, back_plane_p3);
    auto auto_back_point = CGAL::intersection(back_plane, *line);
    Point_3* back_point = boost::get<Point_3>(&*auto_back_point);

    RT distance1 = CGAL::squared_distance(*back_point, *front_point);
    RT distance2 = CGAL::squared_distance(*back_point, *candidate_point);
    return CGAL::compare(distance1, distance2);
}

};

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef CGAL::Exact_kernel_selector<K>::Exact_kernel Exact_kernel;
typedef CGAL::Exact_kernel_selector<K>::C2E C2E;
typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Interval_nt_advanced>        Approximate_kernel;
typedef CGAL::Cartesian_converter<K, Approximate_kernel>   C2F;


typedef CGAL::Filtered_predicate<ClosestPlaneToPoint_1D_imp<Exact_kernel>,
                                 ClosestPlaneToPoint_1D_imp<Approximate_kernel>,
                                 C2E,
                                 C2F>  ClosestPlaneToPoint_1D;

int main()
{
  ClosestPlaneToPoint_1D pred;

  K::Point_3 p1p1, p1p2, p1p3, p2p1, p2p2, p2p3;
  K::Point_3 cp1, cp2, cp3;
  K::Point_3 fp1, fp2, fp3;
  K::Point_3 bp1, bp2, bp3;

  pred(p1p1, p1p2, p1p3, p2p1, p2p2, p2p3,
       cp1, cp2, cp3,
       fp1, fp2, fp3,
       bp1, bp2, bp3);
}
```

of course it will crash at runtime but it's because all points are default constructed.

Comment: typedef CGAL::Exact_kernel_selector<K>::Exact_kernel Exact_kernel  solved my problem. Thanks! Still, I get another strange error. Depending on the printfs that I put on various lines, I get differerent errors at different points. Indeed, getting an error is not a problem since my data may be erroneous. However, getting the error at different lines at each time makes me confused. Does Exact_kernel work with threads or something like that? May it occur because of some asynchronism?

Comment: If you use CGAL 5.5 you should not get any issue with threads.

Comment: I am using CGAL 5.3.

Comment: As stated [here](https://github.com/CGAL/releases/blob/main/CHANGES.md) thread safety for EPECK was introduced in 5.4